# ¿Como selecionar un elemento html por el id desde el ts con Ionic?

Tags: angular, ionic, ionic-framework, ionic2

Necesito seleccionar la instancia de un elemento `html` por su `id` desde el `ts` de una `page` de `ionic`, ¿como haga esto?

Comment: Hola Daniel. Has de mostrar lo que has intentado y explicar por qué no te funciona. para que sobre eso podamos ayudarte a mejorarlo. Un saludo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yo **NO usaría** un selector por ID, **usaría un selector por referencia**, pero te dejo los dos en caso de que tengas tus razones para hacerlo de una u otra forma:

> POR ID:

```
document.getElementById('myID')
```

> POR REF:

HTML:

```
<span #MyRef>Quiero este elemento a escoger</span>
```

TS:

```
import { ElementRef, ViewChild, ngAfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('MyRef') element: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit() {
      console.log(this.element);
}
```

Comment: este: document.getElementById('myID') no funciona, siempre sale null, el de referencia si funciona, yo quiero saber por que por id no funciona en ionic

Comment: Si funciona. El hecho de que lo uses en Ionic no cambia nada, al final es Angular el framework sobre el que corre. Para que te funcione, tienes que usarlo dentro del ciclo ngOnInit(). Lo estas usando ahi o en el constructor? en el constructor nunca funcionara

Comment: Porque por ID y no por su ng-model?. Me parece más correcto que utilizar jquery la verdad.

Comment: El quiere acceder al elemento, no a su valor solo y exclusivamente. con ngModel seria la mejor opcion solo para su valor. Como puedes leer en negrita en mi comentario, yo no usaria un selector para acceder al dom directamente, pero la opcion existe. Por cierto, eso no es jQuery.